# mySQL request not working

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm not really much into PHP or mySQL so I hope you can help me.
I got a php script with a function that returns a json with all the entries in a database table:

```
public function select($table, $wheres = null)
{
    $connect = $this->connect();

    if ($wheres == null)
    {
        $query = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT * FROM `'.$table.'`');
    } else {
        $query = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT * FROM `'.$table.'` WHERE '.$this->wheres($wheres));
    }

    $i = 0;
    $ret = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            $ret[$i][$key] = $value;
        }

        $i++;
    }

    return ($ret);
}
```

Edit:

I have my application which calls this function. Everything worked as expected but then I added 2 more fields to one of the tables ( 1 text, 1 varchar ), and now when I call this function it returns nothing ; literally an empty string.

I've also noticed that if I just delete those new fields it works, which is kinda annoying plus I need those fields and I can't figure out where the problem root is.

Also, the application code is not the problem: when this function is called it only passes 2 parameters (the method name, and the table name), it can't be wrong.

By the way, here is the table structure if it may help you help me:

[pic related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Bfc.png)

Comment: I just deleted the last 2 two fields ( the ones I added and then it stopped working ) and now everything is fine, which is cool, but I'm really annoyed about why those 2 flieds made the script return nothing.

Comment: Please specify "Doesn't work". The problem is not in the code you posted but most probably in the code that calls this function and expects the behavior to be different. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it might help you. Also comments are useful to discuss the problem but you can edit your original answer with additional information instead of posting it as comment.

Comment: I'll take note of that, anyways I edited it, but still can't see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This function helps you to get data form database in `json` from , this return `json`

```
<?php
function getData($tbl_name=null,$id=null)
{
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb"); //my db is my database name
    if(!$con){ die( "could't connect with database" ); } 

    $sql = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id = {"$id"}');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
        #echo"<pre>";
        #print_r($row);       //this will return data form data base in array from
        return json_encode($row);

    }

}
?>
```